# Prototype.js overriding exoskeleton.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, prototypejs, backbone-events, exoskeleton.js

I am using exoskeleton.js@0.6.0 in one of my widgets that customers can implement in there websites.

Now one of them is using prototype.js@1.7.1 and unfortunately he has to load my script after prototype.js (working if he loads it before).

The Problem is that prototype.js is somehow overriding the `off` (aka `unbind`) method of exoskeleton. `off` is `undefined` while `on` (aka `bind`) is working.

Hope you have some experience with prototype.js.

Comment: BTW From what I've heard... prototype.js modifies the prototypes of builtin objects... which is not a good thing to do...

Comment: yeah I heard that too but i can't understand why it is undefined when the script is loading after prototype.js, so obviously I would override prototype.js...

Comment: BTW thanks for editing

Comment: Taking a quick look at both source codes - PrototypeJS does not add any methods named `off` and it registers `Event` not `Events` so that shouldnt conflict either. Have you looked at the widget source code, to see what it is implementing?

Comment: You are right Prototype does not implemtent/register it, gonna take a deeper look at it.

Comment: Checked the widget code and I am not able to find anything wrong.
Tested with an example on the internet (http://todomvc.com/examples/exoskeleton/) and used exoskeleton@0.6.3 and prototype@1.7.1 - got the same error. Again no clue why...